# Problem adding NetBeans IDE to Docky Unity

Tags: icons, netbeans, docky

I have installed `docky` and `numix-icon-theme-circle`, and now that I have installed those I want to pin my favourite programs there permanently, and all was fine until I tried to do so with NetBeans IDE. I don't know if it is something to do with the theme (as it does not have a custom icon for that), or some strange thing going on in `docky`. But as I am able to pin more programs, I don't think that it is to do with some limit in `docky`.

So to get to explaining how the problem actually presents itself, unlike other programs, when I launch NetBeans IDE, instead of seeing:

[image]

I only see these options and so I am unable to pin it:

[image]

So why is this that there is no option to pin it to Dock? Is there any way I can add the option or pin NetBeans IDE to Dock?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
docky:
  Installed: 2.2.0-2
  Candidate: 2.2.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't defined NetBeans' `StartupWMClass`.

To fix this issue, run this command (copy-paste it all at once):

```
echo "StartupWMClass=NetBeans IDE 8.0.2" \
| sudo tee -a /usr/share/applications/netbeans-8.0.2.desktop
```

This will add the WMClass for Netbeans to the desktop file, allowing Netbeans to be pinned.

Finally, log out and log back in. NetBeans should be able to be pinned.

---

As a side-note, the logo is going to be rather low-resolution.

To fix this, run the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install icnsutils
cd /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb
sudo icns2png -x -s 128x128 -d 32 netbeans.icns
sudo mv netbeans.png netbeans.png.bak
sudo mv netbeans_128x128x32.png netbeans.png
```

This will install the `icnsutil` package which contains the utility `icns2png` (which converts ICNS files to PNG). Then, we invoke this to generate a 128x icon for Netbeans, which we then move to the `netbeans.png` file.

Comment: Do you have to log out and then back in again? Is there not a faster way of just reloading it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Usually it will just update itself, but just relaunching Docky (`killall docky && docky` in Alt+F2) will sometimes do it. Relogging ensures that it works, though.

Comment: Since I changed to Ubuntu Gnome, this no longer works... Do you have any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Not for Ubuntu Gnome. I'm not sure how it identifies widows. I'll keep you posted if i see something.

Comment: Ok, I have posted a question about it [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/651878/problem-adding-netbeans-ide-to-docky-ubuntu-gnome).