# Problem adding NetBeans IDE to Docky Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, netbeans, docky

I previously asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/650342/364819) question on how to get NetBeans IDE to pin to `docky` under Unity, however now that I have moved to Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/650698/364819) no longer works to get NetBeans IDE to pin. So that is really my question, how do I get this to work on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `.desktop` file, eg:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/opt/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans
Icon=netbeans
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=NetBeans
```

In `/usr/share/applications/` or in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

After that, open the <kbd>Activities</kbd> menu and type `Netbeans`. Move the icon with the left mouse button in the panel on the left hand site. That's all.

---

But there seems to be a problem. After the start of NetBeans, I have two icons if NetBeans is started. To solve this problem, you have to write your own start script instead of using `/opt/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans`